# How to make cron job in Prestashop?

Tags: cron, prestashop

I need to compute a cronjob for a module and i don't know how to do that. How could i create a cronjob for a module to submit a button at every hour,day,etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience i've scheduled a cron job to fetch an url.
This URL was referring to a module i developed with a front controller.

Of course I had to set up some kind of security due to protect the URL to be called by an unauthorized user.

Resuming:

- Create a module
- Create a modulefrontcontroller
- Create a method/function/something inside that controller
- Schedule a CURL

---

Elseway there are some modules on the prestashop market.